# Disable Last Message Repeated X Times on Syslog Facility

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

Sometimes Syslog send line like that :

```
Aug 12 20:35:57 server sshd[15984]: last message repeated 2 times
```

I know that we can disable it, in the rsyslog config file :

```
$RepeatedMsgReduction off
```

Source : [here](http://hummy.wikidot.com/last-message-repeated-x-times)

That config disable this feature on all syslog facilities.

But my question is : is there any way to disable this feature on only a specific facility (local1 for example) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, according to the [manual](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/global/options/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html) this option only accepts values *on* and *off*. Likewise, the [source code](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/master/runtime/rsconf.h) only documents these two values:

```
int bReduceRepeatMsgs; /* reduce repeated message - 0 - no, 1 - yes */
```

Comment: Ok thanks for this information. So there is no native option to select facility ?